# Loop in Airflow 2.x Task not recognizing task

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow-2.x

What im trying to do is that i want to run a BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator x number of times, it depends on how many files are in bucket (one for every file). For filling the list, I use list_blobs

```
bucket='dagA'
prefix="test/"
delimiter="/"
gcsConnectionId = 'google_cloud_default'
project =models.Variable.get("Project")
storage_client = storage.Client()
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket, prefix=prefix, delimiter="/") 
file_list=[]

    def lista():
        print("Blobs:")
        for blob in blobs:
            if blob.name=='test/'
                continue
            else:
               names=str(blob.name)
               print("file_name: ", names)
               file_list.append(names)
        print("File List: ", file_list)
        if delimiter:
            print("Prefixes:")
            for prefix in blobs.prefixes:
            print(prefix)
        print(file_list)

     python_lista = PythonOperator(
        task_id='lista_python', 
        python_callable=lista, 
        dag=dag
        )
```

and then, creating the task that should be looping x number of times.

```
   for i in file_list:
        crear_tabla = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
            task_id=f"create_table_"+(i),
            dataset_id=DATASET,
            table_id='prueba'+(i),
            schema_fields=[
                {"name": "emp_name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
                {"name": "salary", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
            ],
        )
        lista >> crear_tabla
```

but the second task doesn't appear in the Tasks

[WEB UI Task doesn't appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pulpX.png)

It's the first time I'm trying something like this and I'm a little bit lost.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the top-level DAG code runs basically everywhere (in the scheduler, the dag processor, in workers, etc.), but the code inside of operators runs *only* on workers.  Therefore you cannot use global variables like `file_list` in this way.  When the DAG is evaluated and Tasks are being created, `lista` has not run yet, so `file_list` is still empty.

If you are on Airflow >= 2.3.0, you can use [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) to accomplish this.

Otherwise, you have a few options as listed in [Dynamic DAG Generation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#dynamic-dag-generation).  However, note that whatever you do at the [top level](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code) needs to be fast enough to not slow down DAG parsing.

Another option is to simply combine this work into a single task rather than trying to generate dynamic tasks.